# Make mod_alias work with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

mod_alias rule:

```
/water    /local/path1/water
```

Target URLs:

```
http://www.mysite.com/water/css/style.css
http://www.mysite.com/water/js/java.js
```

Actual URLs:

```
http://www.mysite.com/water/css.php?src=style.css
http://www.mysite.com/water/js.php?src=java.js
```

Mod rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/water/css/([^/]+)$ /local/path1/water/css.php?src=$1 [PT] 
RewriteRule ^/water/js/([^/]+)$ /local/path1/water/js.php?src=$1 [PT]
```

**Problem:** it's not working and I am getting 404 errors and the error says  this
script `/www/mysite.com/htdocs/css.php` not found or unable to start

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I do not have much experience working with mod_alias .. but I think you are doing wrong by rewriting to `/local/path1/water/` -- mod_rewrite does URL rewriting, so it should be URL here as well.

**2.** I will assume that `/local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI}` is correct construction and it references correct file. But ... you apply them (these 2 conditions) to a first rewrite rule only ...

**3.** As I understand these rules are placed in server config / VirtualHost context and not in .htaccess.

Taking all this together you should try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/water/css/([^/]+\.css)$ /water/css.php?src=$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond /local/path1/water%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/water/js/([^/]+\.js)$ /water/js.php?src=$1 [L,PT]
```